# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i write a select element and assign a method searchFeeds

```
<select size="1" onchange="searchFeeds();">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

i write a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function searchFeeds(){
          console.log("current value is",$(this).val());
}
```

it is giving me error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined` 
i want to know what is $(this) represents in this case select elment or some thing elese ??

Comment: global window object i suppose

Comment: You are not calling `toLowerCase` anywhere???

Comment: As @A.Wolff says, $(this) refers to `Window`. This is because of JavaScripts lexical scoping.

Comment: @Bergi isn't lowercase used internally?

Comment: @A.Wolff: oops, you're right - I should've tried the code myself. Indeed `.val()` does retrieve the `.nodeName` (in this case from `window`) and calls `toLowerCase()` on it in order to choose the appropriate value hook.

Comment: since you are using jquery it is better to set up listeners out of your markup like $("select").on("change", searchFeeds)

Answer (score 3):

Change the html like this

```
 <select size="1" onchange="searchFeeds(this);">
```

Then change the console log to this

```
 function searchFeeds(elm) {
        console.log("current value is" + $(elm).val());
    }
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work instead its not showing anything in console.

Comment: It's working on http://jsfiddle.net/MLCps/ there must be something wrong somewhere else

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta Maybe because you have to not wrap code due to how jsfiddle handle load/ready function

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending the information with the function call:
Try this and see the difference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function searchFeeds(x){
          console.log("current value is " + x);
}
</script>

<select size="1" onchange="searchFeeds(this.value);">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , update you function call

```
searchFeeds(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$("select").val()` instead but you better add id to your select and call `$("#myselect").val()`